# RegEx in Delphi to strip off carriage return and line feeds in a string

Tags: regex, delphi

In javascript, I use the next code to strip off linefeeed and carriage return of  a string and it works well:

```
var values="something....."
var sanit=values.replace(/(\r?\n|\r\n?)/g, "");
```

In Delphi, I am trying the next code:

```
values="something....."
sanit:=TRegex.Replace(values,'/(\r?\n|\r\n?)/g', '');
```

But it doesn´t work. No replace is done.

Comment: Find out if Delphi uses delimiters in regex. and about language escaping, and parameter order of the replace. Also, if the replace automatically replaces all (don't need g)

Comment: Delphi uses PCRE I believe. Read the docs on that regex flavour.

Comment: Also, this regex is sufficient `(?:\r?\n|\r)+`

Comment: Why use a regex if StringReplace will do? ISTM that it should be a little faster and simpler to use.

Comment: Why not use the [SysUtils.StringReplace](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace)? `sanit := StringReplace(values,#$D#$A,'',[rfReplaceAll]);`

Comment: Using regex for this task is much like using a tow truck to haul a power wheels toy car.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't necessarily need RegEx for this task. This can also be done with the function [`StringReplace`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/System.SysUtils.StringReplace):

```
StringReplace(value, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll])
```

or

```
StringReplace(StringReplace(value, sLineBreak, '', [rfReplaceAll]), #10#13, '', [rfReplaceAll])
```

to replace both combinations of `#10` (`\n`) and `#13` (`\r`).

Constant `sLineBreak` is located in unit `System` and is declared as `#13#10` (or in Hex: `#$0D#$0A`), when the selected target platform is Windows.

Comment: Or just use [Trim](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.Trim) if specifically looking to remove whitespace and control characters from only the start and end of the string.

Comment: Thank you, as I am working in a front end using JS I tried make the similar code in delphi.It seems TRegex.Replace(values,'\R', '') works well. But your solution works as well